# LaunchDaemon IPC to notify multiple GUI agents on 10.5+

Tags: python, objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a LaunchDaemon written in python that performs a long and resource intensive background task with root privileges. As it works it needs to send status updates to multiple GUI agents (one per logged in user) and I'm struggling to find an appropriate IPC mechanism. Shared objects won't work since the daemon and agents run in a different bootstrap context. I can't have the daemon open a socket, since it's incapable of replying for long periods of time and clients would have to poll for updates. The best I've come up with is for each agent to open its own socket and the daemon writing to each one in turn, but that seems inelegant at best. Are there any other options? Oh, and it must work on Mac OS X 10.5 and up.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having each GUI agent create a datagram socket under /tmp, and then the launchdaemon sends a message to each one in turn and cleans up stale sockets:

```
SOCKET_DIR = "/tmp"
SOCKET_NAME = "se.gu.it.dafgu_migration_status"

status_socket = None

def set_status_menu(status, message):
    global status_socket
    try:
        if status_socket is None:
            status_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        if status_socket is not None:
            message = serializePlist({
                "DAFGUMigrationStatus": status,
                "DAFGUMigrationMessage": message,
            })
            for item in os.listdir(SOCKET_DIR):
                if item.startswith(SOCKET_NAME):
                    socket_path = os.path.join(SOCKET_DIR, item)
                    logging.debug("Sending message to %s" % socket_path)
                    try:
                        status_socket.sendto(message, socket_path)
                    except socket.error, e:
                        if e[0] == errno.ECONNREFUSED:
                            logging.info("Removing stale socket %s" % socket_path)
                            os.unlink(socket_path)
                        else:
                            logging.warn("Sending to %s failed: %s" % (socket_path, e))
    except BaseException, e:
        logging.debug("Unhandled exception when updating status menu: %s" % e)
```

The full implementation can be found at github:

- https://github.com/MagerValp/DAFGU-rsync-wrapper (background process)
- https://github.com/MagerValp/DAFGU-Migration-Status (GUI status menu)